# Build Sveltekit using edge versions of packages

Tags: vite, sveltekit

### Problem

How can I tell Sveltekit to build using the edge compatible version of npm packages?

### Error

I'm using Jose, a fairly popular library for JWT authentication. However, when I use it in Sveltekit on Vercel's edge, I get the following build errors:

```
Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-vercel
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "buffer"

    .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/auth.js:3:23:
      3 │ import { Buffer } from "buffer";
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~

  The package "buffer" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you
  trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove
  this error.
```

I also get the same errors for crypto, util, and zlib.

### Configuration

```js
// svelte.config.js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-vercel'
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            runtime: 'edge',
        }),
    }
}
```

### Hypothesis

Because the build errors occur after all bundles are logged in the console, it seems like this error occurs after the main build step. It's as if:

1. Sveltekit builds the entire application.
2. The Vercel adapter checks that the build is compatible with the edge runtime.

If that's the case, then Sveltekit bundles the npm libraries assuming it'll be deployed on NodeJS.

### References

- [Jose supports Vercel's edge](https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/301)
- [Vercel has an example of Jose on their edge with NextJS](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-middleware/jwt-authentication)
- [There was a similar issue posted in Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3772)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Vercel does not support native node libs out of the box which Jose utilizes. You may need to polyfill them in your Svelt config with something like `rollup-plugin-polyfill-node`.

Comment: Also [Vercel mentions](https://vercel.com/guides/library-sdk-compatible-with-vercel-edge-runtime-and-functions) that you might want to use [node-jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jose) instead.

Comment: So yes, Vercel edge does not support these native node libs. The issue here is that `jose` distributes a version that does not rely on these native node libs by using `"exports": { "browser": "./dist/browser/index.js" }` in it's package.json. So Sveltekit is bundling the wrong version. For what it's worth, I could try `node-jose` like Vercel suggests. However, I'd still like to solve the root of this question since I've run into this issue with several packages, not just `jose`.

Comment: You mention _"I've run into this issue with several packages"_. Can you include those packages in your post as well?